# How to create auto generate id for ListOf rows returned

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am accessing list of data as shown below.

```
var result = (from Pages in PagesList.Items.OfType<SPListItem>()
select new ListImages
{
  desc = Convert.ToString(Pages["Description"])
}).ToList();
```

What I want is to auto generate customized increamental id for the no of rows generated.
ex, **slide-img-1, slide-img-2** etc.

```
public class ListImages
{
    string _desc;   
    string _id;
     public string id
    {
        get
        {
            if (_id != null)
                return _id;
            else
                return string.Empty;
        }
        set { _id = value; }
    }
    public string desc
    {
        get
        {
            if (_desc != null)
                return _desc;
            else
                return string.Empty;
        }
        set { _desc = value; }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Ashish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it can be achieved with the Linq specific syntax, but writing your *query* like this, you could use the **[.Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx)** method that provides an index:

```
var result = PagesList.Items.OfType<SPListItem>()
    .Select((page, index) => new ListImages
                                 {
                                     desc = Convert.ToString(page["Description"]),
                                     id = String.Concat("slide-img-", index + 1)
                                 })
    .ToList();
```